# Cannot download google credentials json file

Tags: gcloud, google-api-client

At this website
https://cloud.google.com/life-sciences/docs/how-tos/getting-started#download_credentials_for_api_access
it says:

> After creating your credentials, download the client_secret.json file by going to the Credentials page in the Cloud Console and clicking Download JSON file_download.

The credentials page is hyperlinked.  But when you go to that page there is no such button named download json file.  Here is a screenshot of the page:

[image: page]

I really wish Google would learn to write clear documentation.

I should also add that the website has the following cryptic instructions:

> Use this key in your application by passing it with key=API_KEY parameter.

I don't know what it means to pass a key.  If the writers would have provided an example that would certainly have helped.  I have the key and that might solve my problem, I just don't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 8):

This may be late, but this may help if anyone is still having this issue

1. After creating the service account
2. Select/click the from the account listing
3. Goto the keys tab
4. Click Add Key and select create key
5. Then select JSON and the file will be downloaded

refer here https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started?authuser=1#creating_a_service_account

Answer (score 2):

You haven't made a OAuth credential. 
`Click Create credentials > Oauth Client ID.
Set the application type to Other and complete the form.
After creating your credentials, download the client_secret.json file by going to the Credentials page in the Cloud Console and clicking Download JSON file_download. Securely store the file in a location that only your application can access.`

Comment: I'm not building an app however.  I'm just making some calculations for myself. By clicking oauth credential, they want me to input a web address where my app will reside and I have none.

Comment: Just put an app name in OAuth consent screen and leave everything else empty and save. Worked for me, there is no json file to download for API-KEY. The DL button will appear after youve made OAuth credential.

Answer (score 0):

The write of the documentation linked to the wrong page.  He should have linked to

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/

But instead linked to

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

If you can download the json file with the first link then more instructions will be needed.  The second link though allows you to download the json file.

Answer (score 0):

After creating the keys and service account, you can download the Json file on the end right side of OAuth key IDs. Check the picture below for the location of the button.

[image: json download button]